# How to save a float numpy array to a binary file with less storage (e.g.: not in scientific notation)?

Tags: python, numpy, binary, save

Assume that I have a big float numpy array:

How to save this float numpy array to a binary file with less storage using numpy.save?

```
np.save(nucleosomenpyOutputFilePath,averageSignalArray)
```

Comment: What's the current `dtype`?

Comment: I got this numpy array by the following statement `averageSignalArray=np.divide(accumulatedSignalArray,accumulatedCountArray)`  I guess its dtype=float

Comment: Do you know what I mean by `dtype`?

Comment: Yes, of course dtype.

Comment: There's `float32` and `float64`, 4 and 8 bytes per element.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @hpaulj. You openedmy eyes.

By playing with dtype=np.float32 or dtype=np.float16 in the following statements

```
averageSignalArray=np.divide(accumulatedSignalArray,accumulatedCountArray,dtype=np.float32)
averageSignalArray=np.divide(accumulatedSignalArray,accumulatedCountArray,dtype=np.float16)
```

I got different nparrays and save them in the following step:

```
np.save(nucleosomenpyOutputFilePath,averageSignalArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to just save size on the resulting files and you can install additional python packages and use compressed arrays. https://github.com/Blosc/bcolz

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the fastest and most space-efficient ways of doing this is by using Bloscpack:

https://github.com/blosc/bloscpack

You can read about using the Python API here:

https://github.com/blosc/bloscpack#python-api

And lastly, here is an example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import bloscpack as bp
>>> a = np.linspace(0, 1, 3e8)
>>> print a.size, a.dtype
300000000 float64
>>> bp.pack_ndarray_to_file(a, 'a.blp')
>>> b = bp.unpack_ndarray_from_file('a.blp')
>>> (a == b).all()
True
```